# Permission Access

Tags: wireshark

Recently I downloaded wireshark from store but mistakely forgot to give permission for all users to use it. Is there any way to change it? I tried to reinstall but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried purging as opposed to just removing?  Also, please make sure you add more information like version number of Ubuntu as well as the version of the package you are trying to instal.

Answer (score 2):

Read `man dpkg-reconfigure`, and do:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark
```